# How to set position fixed of Div having(search button) during search functionality

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am doing search functionality .Search functionality is working fine.Problem is that when I start search It hide my Buttons(search , next , Previous).I will explain more.

1. search for word "Sachin"
2. Then press search it show sachin on same page But when you again click search /next it goes to next text But Buttons previous/next/search hide(go above).I need to show this button the page while searching.I thing I need to add fixed height where div contend scroll?
3. This is problem Because if user click Third time it goes above then click search then search item goes down .Then again it goes up .It look so awe word.

I need to fixed these Buttons on page while searching.

http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/3xbGW/

```
var searchIndex = -1;
var searchTermOld ='';

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.searchbox').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).val()===''){
      var  selector= "#realTimeContents";
     $(selector+' span.match').each(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
      });
    }
      searchIndex = -1;
      $('.searchNext').attr("disabled", "disabled");
      $('.searchPrev').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    searchTermOld = $(this).val();
  });
  $('.searchbox').on('keyup',function(){

    var  selector= "#realTimeContents";
    if($(this).val()===''){
     $(selector+' span.match').each(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
      });
    }
    if($(this).val() !== searchTermOld){
     $(selector+' span.match').each(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
      });
      searchIndex = -1;
      $('.searchNext').attr("disabled", "disabled");
      $('.searchPrev').attr("disabled", "disabled");                              
  }
  });
  $('.search').on('click',function(){


    if(searchIndex == -1){
      var searchTerm = $('.searchbox').val();
      if(searchTerm==''){
         alert("Please Insert Text.")
        return ;
      }
      searchAndHighlight(searchTerm);
    }
    else searchNext();
    if($('.match').length >1){
      $('.searchNext').removeAttr("disabled");
      $('.searchPrev').removeAttr("disabled");
    }
  });
  $('.searchNext').on('click',searchNext);

  $('.searchPrev').on('click',searchPrev);
});

function searchAndHighlight(searchTerm) {
    if (searchTerm) {
        var searchTermRegEx, matches;
        var  selector= "#realTimeContents";
        $(selector+' span.match').each(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
      });
        try {
            searchTermRegEx = new RegExp('('+searchTerm+')', "ig");
        } catch (e) {
            return false;
        }
        $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
        matches = $(selector).text().match(searchTermRegEx);
                if (matches !==null && matches.length > 0) {
            var txt = $(selector).text().replace(searchTermRegEx, '<span class="match">$1</span>');
            $(selector).html(txt);
            searchIndex++;
           $('.match:first').addClass('highlighted');
         if($('.match').eq(searchIndex).offset().top > $(window).height()-10){
  $(document).scrollTop($('.match').eq(searchIndex).offset().top);
}
          return true;
        }else{
          alert('Search not found.');
        }
      return false;
    }
  return false;
}

function searchNext(){
  searchIndex++;
  if (searchIndex >= $('.match').length) searchIndex = 0;
  $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
  $('.match').eq(searchIndex).addClass('highlighted');
if($('.match').eq(searchIndex).offset().top > $(window).height()-10){
  $(document).scrollTop($('.match').eq(searchIndex).offset().top);
}
}

function searchPrev(){
  searchIndex--;
  if (searchIndex < 0) searchIndex = $('.match').length - 1;
  $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
  $('.match').eq(searchIndex).addClass('highlighted');
 if($('.match').eq(searchIndex).offset().top > $(window).height()-10){
  $(document).scrollTop($('.match').eq(searchIndex).offset().top);
}
}
```

Comment: John, please edit your question.  It's very difficult to understand, and your demo doesn't do anything because `PG_alert is undefined` (I do appreciate the effort of making a fiddle, though).  If english isn't your first language, perhaps Google translate could help.

Comment: Sorry I will remove this ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an id to your search div and set its postion to fixed

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui-grid-c" id="searchbar">
    <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text" autocorrect="off" class="searchbox"> 
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" data-inline="true" class="search">Search</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" data-inline="true" id="next" class="searchNext" disabled>Next</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" data-inline="true" id="prev" class="searchPrev" disabled>Previous</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#searchbar .ui-btn {
    width: 8em;
}
#searchbar .ui-input-text {
    display: inline-block;
}
#searchbar {
    position: fixed;
}
#searchbar + * {
    margin-top: 70px;
}
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xbGW/5/)** - Now the buttons are always visible but they may cover up the search result

### **UPDATE**

I have devised a better solution. This time I removed the fixed position of the searchbar, instead I made it so the content is scrollable and whenever a new search match is highlighted the content is scrolled, leaving the searchbar on top.

I made some changes to the script:

Replace the last three functions (`searchAndHighlight()`, `searchNext()` and `searchPrev()`) with the ones below and add a new function `goToMatch()` add the end

**Javascript**

```
function searchAndHighlight(searchTerm) {
    if (searchTerm) {
        var searchTermRegEx, matches;
        var selector = "#realTimeContents";
        $(selector + ' span.match').each(function () {
            $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
        });
        try {
            searchTermRegEx = new RegExp('(' + searchTerm + ')', "ig");
        } catch (e) {
            return false;
        }
        $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
        matches = $(selector).text().match(searchTermRegEx);
        if (matches !== null && matches.length > 0) {
            var txt = $(selector).text().replace(searchTermRegEx, '<span class="match">$1</span>');
            $(selector).html(txt);
            searchIndex++;
            goToMatch();

            return true;
        } else {
            alert('Search not found.');
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

function searchNext() {
    searchIndex++;
    if (searchIndex >= $('.match').length) searchIndex = 0;
    goToMatch();
}

function searchPrev() {
    searchIndex--;
    if (searchIndex < 0) searchIndex = $('.match').length - 1;
    goToMatch()
}

function goToMatch(){
    $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
    $('.match').eq(searchIndex).addClass('highlighted');
    $('#realTimeContents').animate({ scrollTop: $('.match').eq(searchIndex).get(0).offsetTop});
}
```

And for the new element styles you need to add this to your CSS:

**CSS**

```
.ui-page.ui-body-c.ui-page-active {
    height: 100%;
}
#realTimeContents {
    max-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: auto!important;
}
#searchbar .ui-btn {
    width: 8em;
}
#searchbar .ui-input-text {
    display: inline-block;
}
#searchbar {
    background: #333;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Check out the **[new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xbGW/9/)**

Comment: It seam's that Buttons and text field are above the div contend ?.But I think it is not looking good..May I used Iscroller ? Here ? for better looking

Comment: Hello why  the search text accumulate ? here is my fiddle ..http://jsfiddle.net/3xbGW/14/.Press forth button it show search field .search "naveen" naveen come up automatically .accumulation ?

Comment: I used your code .I am facing a same problem as john .I used text instead of html?but no success